# How to "Scroll To Top" in Native Base <Content> Component?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I'm using `Expo` and implement `Native Base` on it, I'm trying to do "Scroll to Top" whenever "MainTabNavigator" Icon `<Ionicons/>`

Should the handle implemented in `<Content>`or in the `<Ionicons/>` (in MainTabNavigator)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this

```
 <Container>
    <Content ref={c => (this.component = c)}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>test</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>test</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>test</Text>
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...

      <Button onPress={() => this.component._root.scrollToPosition(0, 0)}>
        <Text>Back to top</Text>
      </Button>
    </Content>
  </Container>
```

[image]

Comment: Smartest developer is straight and sharp like you, bro. It's work like a magic. Thx.